# Prestashop iframe

Tags: session, iframe, prestashop

Hi I'm trying to insert a prestashop website in an iframe but I have to remove the header and the footer. My idea is to pass a value to the page and then set up a session, then entering the pages if the session has a value I hide the header and footer. How can I do it? Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Add the parameter `content_only=1` to the URL to discard the header and the footer.

Example:

```
https://myshop.com/?content_only=1
```

If your URL already has other parameters, then use the ampersand like so

```
https://myshop.com/?lang=1&content_only=1
```